# How to get UTC time given timezone?

Tags: python, time, utc

I am in the US and I want to get the UTC time (without the effect of Daylight Saving Time) for a piece of code:

```
localtime = strftime("%m%d%y%H%M", gmtime())
```

Right now that code give me time in Greenwich, England. I know that I have a time offset of -8 (GMT -8). How can I get the UTC time to a specific timezone? (using Python library, not casting the hour to integer, - 8, and than convert it back)

Comment: Your phrase "UTC time in the US" is a bit strange. UTC time is UTC time. I think you mean "how can I get UTC time local to a specific time zone in the US.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the datetime module:

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=-8)
```

BTW, UTC doesn't have timezones, it's Universal Co-ordinated Time, it's the same everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the localtime() rather than gmtime() function:

```
localtime = time.strftime("%m%d%y%H%M", time.localtime())
```

From the python time module:
"Like gmtime() but converts to local time. If secs is not provided or None, the current time as returned by time() is used. The dst flag is set to 1 when DST applies to the given time."

To see if DST applies:

```
time.daylight
```

Answer (score 1):

> Supporting timezones at whatever level of detail is required is up to the application. The rules for time adjustment across the world are more political than rational, and there is no standard suitable for every application.

There is a useful third party module for that purpose: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/