# How to compare two timezone strings?

Tags: python, timezone, timezone-offset

Is there some library or built-in to compare two timezones? What I want is the offset of hours between two timezones

For example:

```
hours = diff_timezones("America/Los_Angeles", "America/Sao_Paulo")

print(hours) # -> 3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get hours difference from UTC to given timezone with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329904/get-hours-difference-from-utc-to-given-timezone-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI: Python 3.9+ ships with [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in its standard library, while dateutil (below) is a third-party package available on PyPI as `python-dateutil`.

---

Using [`dateutil.tz.gettz`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.tz import gettz

def diff_timezones(tz1: str, tz2: str) -> timedelta:
    zero = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
    diff = zero.replace(tzinfo=gettz(tz1)) - zero.replace(tzinfo=gettz(tz2))
    return diff
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> diff_timezones('America/Los_Angeles', 'America/Sao_Paulo')
datetime.timedelta(seconds=18000)
```

The result here is a `datetime.timedelta` instance. To get a float of hours:

```
>>> td.total_seconds() / (60 * 60)
5.0
```

**CAUTION**: I don't believe this would take into account DST since it uses a fixed datetime of the Unix epoch (1970-01-01), so it might be off in cases where one area obeys DST and another does not. To account for that you might be able to use the current timestamp as a reference date instead.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know the dateutil.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.
and here's a great blog about timezones and datetime: [Blog](https://howchoo.com/g/ywi5m2vkodk/working-with-datetime-objects-and-timezones-in-python)

```
import datetime, pytz


d_naive = datetime.datetime.now()

timezone_a = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
timezone_b = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")

d_aware_a = timezone_a.localize(d_naive)
d_aware_b = timezone_b.localize(d_naive)

difference =  d_aware_a - d_aware_b

print(difference.total_seconds() / 60 / 60 ) # seconds / minutes
```